# Is it possible to connect to 2 databases hosted on different servers at the same time using PHP and run queries on the tables?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to insert the incoming data, into a table that exists on a databaseA hosted on server1. In the same code I want to query a few tables that are on databaseB hosted on server2. The code I want to achieve this is written in PHP and is running on server1.
Is there any procedure to achieve this?
I was thinking in this way,

1. Connect to DataBase1 on server 1
2. Insert into table
3. Disconnect from the server1
4. Connect to Database2 on server2
5. query the tables
6. disconnect from server2

If this way works, what could be the disadvantages of it?

Note : I am using PHP 5.3 and mysql_connect()

Comment: **Side note**: You should **NOT** be using `mysql_connect` anymore and should instead be using `mysqli_*` or `PDO` function.

Comment: Yes, you can connect to more than one database server at a time. The main issue would be connectivity and slowness.

Comment: You can connect to any number of different MySQL servers from your code, as long as you have access to them.

Comment: Yes, you can create two connection and both can be used independently even without closing the first server you can access and use the other server.

Comment: As many other say's: **Yes**, just use two different variables for the connections or one variable with an array of the connections, easier to work with.

Comment: mysql_connect('localhost','user_name','password');
  mysql_select_db('dbname');
This is how I am connecting to my database. Now, local host is the existing server on which my server is hosted that is server 1. I want to establish another connection mysql_connect('server2ip','username','passwd');
mysql_select_db('db_name');
This will be a remote connection to the databaseB on server 2. How will the program differentiate the connections?

Comment: Come on, mysql_connect() returns a connection resource representing the connection. How do you think you can distinguish between the connections using this information?